# How can I create a Node js MySQL pool with getconnection method

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pool

I have just stated learning node js, I have this piece of code so far.

```
//Create a mysql connection pool
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodetuts',
    debug    :  false
});

// retrieve database connection
var connection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } 
        console.log('connected');
        callback(err, conn);
        
    });
};

//create tabase tables
connection.getConnection(function(err, conn){
    if (!err){
        console.log("Connected!");
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream('struct.sql'),
            terminal: false
        });
        rl.on('line', function(chunk){
            conn.query(chunk.toString('ascii'), function(err, sets, fields){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log("Table created");
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
module.exports = connection;
```

I want create tables function to run within this module but use the same for connection in other modules.

Create table function generates an error,

Any one who can help I will appreciate.

Comment: can you add error message in question?

Comment: Here is the error message      getConnection.getConnection(function(err, conn){
              ^

TypeError: getConnection.  getConnection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\localhost\htdocs\nodejs\tutorial\dao.js:26:15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with the piece of code and I came up with this.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var fs         = require('fs');
var readline   = require('readline');

//Create a mysql connection pool
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodetuts',
    debug    :  false
});

var saveConnection = pool.getConnection(function(err,conn){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    //create tables
    var createTables = function(conn){
        connection.release();
        var rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream('struct.sql'),
            terminal: false
        });
        rl.on('line', function(chunk){
            conn.query(chunk.toString('ascii'), function(err, sets, fields){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log("Table created");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    var findByPrimaryKey = connection.query("select * from user",function(err,rows){
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows);
        }          
    });

    conn.on('error', function(err) {      
        console.log(err);
        return;    
    });
    console.log('connected');
});

module.exports = saveConnection;
```

Now my question is: Can I use methode bellow to access createTables function

```
saveConnection.createTables();
```